# How to create a delay based on an animation in HaxeFlixel?

Tags: animation, haxe, haxeflixel, ludumdare

I'm developing my first game and I have a player class (`FlxSprite`) that has a death animation.

I want to remove the player from the stage as soon as the animation ends, but if I use:

```haxe
player.animation.play('death');
remove(player);
```

The animation doesn't finish and the player just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear, but I'll try help anyway.

Because of the way the game loop is looping, the remove function kills off the sprite before the animation plays. You can check to see when the animation is finished by putting an if statment in your update function, like so.

```
if (animation.finished) kill()
```

If you need an actual timed delay, you can see my previous answer where you increase a variable by [`FlxG.elapsed`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxG.html#elapsed) every update on a variable until it exceeds your timer length.

I hope this answers your question. You may want too look at methods such as `kill()` in the HaxeFlixel docs, as I think you might be confused with `remove()`.

EDIT: very sorry, forgot to include one important detail. It is likely that you are calling animation.play every single frame - stop once your death animation plays. In my code I saw I have an `isDying` variable that stops any new animations starting, and checks to see if the current animation is finished. Without this, the finished variable might not flip.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this in most of my projects is something like this:

```haxe
override public function update(elapsed:Float):Void
{
  if (!alive)
  {
    if (animation.finished)
    {
      exists = false;
    }
    super.update(elapsed);
  }
  // other update stuff...
  super.update(elapsed);
}

override public function kill():Void
{
  if (!alive || !exists)
  {
    return;
  }
  alive = false;
  animation.play("death", true);
  // Note: I DO NOT call super.kill() because I want to leave exists = true
}
```

And, in your PlayState or wherever you want to remove the object, just check `if (!player.exists) remove(player);`, I guess? I don't usually use `remove`, I just wait until the state is destroyed and then clean everything up with `FlxDestroyUtil`.